# Почему меняется расширение файла?

Tags: asp.net, браузер

Отдаю файл клиенту с сервера:

```
Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(file)
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application;name=" + fileInfo.Name
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name)
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString())
Response.WriteFile(file)
Response.Flush()
```

`file` - файл формата `.docx`.
Броузер, как и должно быть, запрашивает "Сохранить или открыть файл?". На `IE` работает как надо, но на `Opera` расширение файла меняется на `.zip`.
Понятно, что `.docx` это тот же самый `.zip`-архив, но с сервера же отдается файл с расширением `.docx`, почему оно меняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это фича оперы, она автоматически определяет zip-архивы и ведет себя не совсем логично.

Comment: Отнюдь, хоть Опера и не всегда логична, но это поведение не ее заслуга. Посмотрите какой бардак у ОПа в `Content-Type` :-)

Comment: Действительно, заменил на  

    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"  

и заработало.